# Both @Change and @Input are not triggering function on Q-Select element

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar

So I am emitting data collected from a form. All Q-Input functions are triggered just fine with @change, however, nothing is happening with any of the Q-Select elements:

```js
       <q-input
        rounded
        standout
        bg-color="grey-3"
        type="text"
        v-model="nombreVehiculo"
        placeholder="Nombre del modelo"
        class="input inputPosition q-mb-md"
        @change="emittedNombreVehiculo"
      />
      <span class="text-black inputLabel">Año</span>
      <q-input
        rounded
        standout
        bg-color="grey-3"
        type="text"
        v-model="fecha"
        placeholder="(2008, 2009, 2010)"
        class="input inputPosition q-mb-md"
        @change="emittedFecha"
      />
      <span class="text-black inputLabel">Transmisión</span>
      <q-select
        rounded
        standout
        bg-color="grey-3"
        type="text"
        v-model="transmision"
        placeholder="(2008, 2009, 2010)"
        class="input inputPosition q-mb-md"
        :options="opcionesTransmision"
        @change="emittedTransmision"
      />

<script>
const opcionesTransmision = ["manual", "automático"];
function emittedTransmision(value) {
  emit("emit:transmision", transmision.value);
  console.log(transmision.value);
}
</script>
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. As I mentioned above, I have attempted using @input but it still does nothing, the function will just not trigger at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@update:model-value="emittedTransmision"`

Codepen - https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/rNvpvBz?editors=1010